# iOS MPMediaQuery.albums().collections returns nil at the first run while user allows access to media library

Tags: ios, swift, media

I try to access the media library but for the first time when the system prompts for access to the media library, the `MPMediaQuery.albums().collections` return nil. It works fine for the second time.

```
MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] (status) in
    if let this = self, status == MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.authorized  {
        let albums = MPMediaQuery.albums().collections
```

runs at application load time. The albums is `nil` when the app is first installed and runs for the first time.

Comment: So don’t do that. Get user authorization before trying to access the media library.

Comment: viewDidLoad, but I guess you mean at AppDelegate, right?

Comment: The problem is right after installation when for the first time the user runs the app and system prompts for access,  even if the user allows it, the value of the albums is nil. This let albums = MPMediaQuery.albums().collections evaluate as nil.

Comment: But you see, I've got apps that ask for authorization and probe the media library on launch, and they work right after installation just fine. So you need to give enough info so that I can see how what _you_ are doing is different from what _I_ do.

Comment: I guess it is a matter of time. I added a 100 ms delay and it is done.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I don't hit this problem because I step out to the main thread before doing my query. See example test project at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch16p678mediaQuery/ch29p946mediaQuery/ViewController.swift

Comment: the other problem in slower iphones show up that when you get access to library before geting the actual user response, the library locks up and you have to restart the app for refreshing library access.

Comment: I doubt that; my app (Albumen) depends on access to the user's music library, and it has run on every iPhone, and even iPod, since the iOS 3.2 days; it has never "locked up" when we get access. I don't know what you're doing, but I've shown you code that works.

Comment: This is strange but just check this and note that it only happens at the first installation. If you run this code it will print zero album counts, assuming you have some albums in your device, but if you comment the line 36, it will print the correct number of the albums.
https://gist.github.com/mehsam/c4e9a6b35b1e1ac7185a9bf5e06a0948#file-medialibraryaccessproblem-swift

Comment: I'm happy to see you're using my code; but you're doing it wrong. You're saying `MPMediaQuery.albums()` _outside_ of, and _before_, a call to `checkForMusicLibraryAccess`. The point of my code is that you do everything _inside_ a call to `checkForMusicLibraryAccess`. That way, you always _do_ have access.

Comment: Please note that the print statement is inside the access block. My point is if you get access the MediaLibary before asking for permision, the MPMediaQuery.albums() (inside the block) will return nil even if the access is granted. but if you don't it will work fine.

Comment: So don't do that then. Unsupported behavior brings undesirable results. Do it the right way and all will be well.

Comment: Thankx for your time, It was a bug and it took a lot of time for me to figure it out and I'd like to share it.

Comment: That sounds great! Answering your own question is totally okay on Stack Overflow.